# .journal files in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Quick google search revealed that

> The rollback journal is always located in the same directory as the
>   database file and has the same name as the database file except with
>   the 8 characters "-journal" appended. The rollback journal is usually
>   created when a transaction is first started and is usually deleted
>   when a transaction commits or rolls back.

That's a lot of "usually" in one sentence.

If at the end of the day, one is left with multiple journal files, what is it a symptom of?

This seems to happen intermittently, i can't reliably reproduce the problem.

How would you troubleshoot an intermittent issue like this please? Would would be a likely culprit?

Update: I am running on OSX 10.8.2, SQLite version 3.7.14.1

Comment: What OS? What version of SQLite?

Comment: What are the names of those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "usually"s are there because SQLite can be configured to use a [persistent rollback journal](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html#section_7_6).

It is not possible to have multiple journals for one database, because it is not possible to have multiple files with the same name.